# ¿Cómo puedo importar librerías externas en angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, express, requirejs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web donde necesito que el usuario genere una llave de acceso en el frontend a través de `angularjs`. Tengo todo controlado hasta el punto en el que necesito acceder a funciones que están definidas en código fuera de angular. Intenté invocando los scripts desde el propio `head` del `html`, y no me reconoce el token `module` ni `module.exports` ni `exports` ni nada parecido.

Necesito la función `randomBytes` del módulo `cryptojs`. Intenté muchas cosas ya y me dicen que necesito instalar `requirejs`, pero busco información y nada parece estar relacionado. No encuentro información explicita sobre integrar `requirejs` en `MEAN`, y realmente no entiendo lo de `requirejs` por mas que lo intento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar a injectarlo a través del servicio $window.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js"/>

angular.module('myApp').factory('myService',['$window',function($window){
  console.log('hmm, slightly less gross, getting moment from $window', $window.moment());
}]);
```

En este ejemplo se utiliza la librería moment desde el servicio $window (que te permite utilizar el objecto document.window).

No es la mejor opción para hacerlo, pero sí es lo más rápido, la fuente es este post: 
http://jameshill.io/articles/angular-third-party-injection-pattern/ (inglés)

(Edit)

He visto que hay un wrapper de criptojs para angular: angular-criptojs, pero parece que está abanadonado, te lo dejo por si te sirve de ayuda:

https://github.com/pussinboots/angularjs-crypto

Comment: Gracias bro, esto me ha ayudado bastante. Ya tengo funcionando la app.